# interpolate.splrep error: 'knots must be given for task =-1'

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares, interpolation, cubic-spline

I'm trying to find a least squared cubic spline fit of data using the following code:

```
from scipy import interpolate
plt.subplot(223)
l_hits = np.array(l_hits)
list1 = np.log(l_hits)
knots = list1.sort()
xnew = np.arange(min(l_bins), max(l_bins))
tck = interpolate.splrep(l_bins,list1,s=0,k=3,task=-1,t=knots)
fnew = interpolate.splev(xnew, tck, der=0)
plt.plot(xnew, fnew, 'b-')
```

where the x-values are *l_bins* and the y-values are *np.log(l_hits) = list1*. But I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: Knots must be given for task =-1
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The numpy [`sort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html) method operates in-place, and returns None, so this line:

```
knots = list1.sort()
```

sets `knots` to None.

To accomplish what I think you intended, you could do something like this:

```
knots = list1.copy()
knots.sort()
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried this and got the error: `raise _iermess[ier][1](_iermess[ier][0]) ValueError: Error on input data`

Comment: That looks like a different problem.  Time for a new SO question?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [API document](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html)

> If provided, knots t must satisfy the Schoenberg-Whitney conditions,
> i.e., there must be a subset of data points x[j] such that t[j] < x[j]
> < t[j+k+1], for j=0, 1,...,n-k-2.

In your case,

```
l_bins = ?
knots = list(np.log(l_hits)).sort()
```

It's unclear whether `knots` satisfies the Schoenberg-Whitney conditions from the question.